# Forbid page ranges in index

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx

I'm using `imakeidx` with `makeindex` and an `.ist` file. How can I forbid `makeindex` from creating page ranges (e.g. `3--5`)?

Comment: Use the `-r` option: `\makeindex[...,options=-r -s myindex.ist]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page range formation is disabled via a command line option, rather than an instruction in the `.ist` file. So the solution is to call `makeindex` with the `-r` option; with `imakeidx` this can be specified in the value for the `option` key; the simplest call would be

```
\makeindex[options= -r]
```

if no other setting for the (main) index is needed. In your case, denoting with `...` other keywords or command line options, something like

```
\makeindex[... , options= -r -s myindex.ist ... , ...]
```

---

**Note** This is `imakeidx` specific. If one doesn't use this package, the call from the command line should be

```
makeindex -r -s myindex.ist filename
```